# Image get misaligned in markdown when using align right or left

Tags: html, css, markdown, hugo

I am trying to add an image wrapped by the text into the `about.md` of hugo based theme (hugo-theme-casper). I am not really an expert of either CSS or HTML, but looking around on different tutorials I managed to create something. The page content looks like:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

<img clear="none" align="right" src="/images/cover.jpg" style="height:250px" > 

Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur
```

The result is that the image gets wrapped by the text but it seems shifted too much towards the right:

[image]

I cannot find a way to move the figure towards the left in order to be more "centered" in the text. I imagine that there are some rules in the theme css file that is modifying the way `align="right"` is working, but this is just a random guess. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

When considering image alignment, you can read "[How to Align and float images with CSS](https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/website-design/align-float-images-css/)"

- aligned imaged can be centered, but the text will *not* wrap around them
- floating image can have the text wrapped around them, but won't be centered

Hugo allows you to add a class that you can [easily customize in your CSS](https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/handling-images-size-aligning/1940):

```html
{{% figure src="/image.png#floatleft" caption="blah blah" %}}
```

css:

```css
img[src$='#floatleft']
{
    float:left;
        //etc. etc/
}
```

But that would not be enough to center *and* wrap an image in a text.

As seen in this [Hugo example](http://www.ebadf.net/2016/10/19/centering-images-in-hugo/), wrapping would only apply to left/right floating images.

[image: images wrap]

Comment: I am trying with what you are suggesting. In the theme folder I can see two css files, `nav.css` and `screen.css`. I tried to add the code snippet (`img[src$='...`) but it did not make any change. I also tried to create a new .css file in that folder including the snippets, but nothing changes either...

Comment: @ValerioD.Ciotti https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/how-to-override-css-classes-with-hugo/3033/2 could help.

Comment: How to do this with flex(box) instead of float? @isherwood

Comment: How to solve this task without float, according to best practice html/css? @Quentin