# propper adjustment of text and list floating around figure/image # flexbox vs float or other methodes

Tags: html, css, image, flexbox, css-float

based on this question:
[Image get misaligned in markdown when using align right or left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63448360/image-get-misaligned-in-markdown-when-using-align-right-or-left)

---

First try with float - sub optimal positioning of bullet points

```css
img {
  float: left;
  margin-left: -52px;
  margin-right: 18px;
}
```

```html
<h2>Float text around an image with text/list</h2>
<p>How to properly solve this with float or flexbox or any other modern method</p>

<p>In this example.</p>
<figure>
<img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/51.jpg" alt="img" style="width:170px;height:170px;margin-right:15px;">
<figcaption>Caption Image</figcaption>
</figure>
<p></p>

<p>Head:</p>

<ul>
  <li> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum inte </li>
  <li>rdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Mauris ante ligula, facilisis sed ornare eu, lobortis in odio. Praesent
    convallis urna a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla
    congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta. Cras ac leo purus. Mauris quis diam velit.</li>
</ul>

<p>The following text/list alignment would be expected to get (right to the image)</p>
<p>Topic :</p>

<ul>
  <li> correct bullet points / list alignment </li>

</ul>
```

---

Second try with flex

```css
figure {
display: flex;
margin-left: -32px;
margin-right: 18px;
}

figcaption {
  padding: 15px;
}

.persOpties {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="persOpties">
<h2>Float text around an image with text/list</h2>
<p>How to properly solve this with float or flexbox or any other modern method</p>

<p>In this example.</p>
<figure>
<img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/51.jpg" alt="img" style="width:170px;height:170px;margin-right:15px;">
<figcaption>Caption Image</figcaption>
</figure>
<p></p>

<p>Head:</p>

<ul>
  <li> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum inte </li>
  <li>rdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Mauris ante ligula, facilisis sed ornare eu, lobortis in odio. Praesent
    convallis urna a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla
    congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta. Cras ac leo purus. Mauris quis diam velit.</li>
</ul>

  </div>
```

---

How to adjust the text and the list to the right of the image with a proper space to the image

with float

- the line bullets are directly at the image - should be like that
- the bullet points would be under aligned with the text, not left to "Head:"

How to get text and list floating around the figure/image with flex/flexbox?

Comment: Have you tried setting `margin` for the image?

Comment: This scenario is what float is for. Put a right hand margin on the img as @BehRouz suggests to move the bullets to the right a bit.

Comment: @AHaworth, margin is added into the img css, what else would it need?

Comment: @isherwood could you explain why float shouldn't be used and how you do it with flex - for this case - to the community? Or do you close valid questions without a reason and refuse a review of it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76255644/correct-distance-between-figure-image-and-text-list-when-float-or-better-flex?noredirect=1#comment134473798_76255644

Comment: @Quentin, you are welcome to add your solution. The question look understandable?

Comment: @isherwood could you be so kind and show the community how to solve the issue with "flex"? or apologize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the bullet points to align with the text above.

list-style-position determines whether they are outside or not. In this case you want them inside.

```css
img {
  float: left;
  margin-left: -52px;
  margin-right: 18px;
}

li {
   list-style-position: inside;
}
```

```html
<h2>Float text around an image with text/list</h2>
<p>How to properly solve this with float or flexbox or any other modern method</p>

<p>In this example.</p>
<figure>
<img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/51.jpg" alt="img" style="width:170px;height:170px;margin-right:15px;">
<figcaption>Caption Image</figcaption>
</figure>
<p></p>

<p>Head:</p>

<p><ul>
  <li> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum inte </li>
  <li>rdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Mauris ante ligula, facilisis sed ornare eu, lobortis in odio. Praesent
    convallis urna a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla
    congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta. Cras ac leo purus. Mauris quis diam velit.</li>
</ul>
</p>

<p>The following text/list alignment would be expected to get (right to the image)</p>
<p>Topic :</p>

<ul>
  <li> correct bullet points / list alignment </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you. How to get the bullet points aligned like in the normal text setting - starting under the "H" not to the left side of it? Like in the example after "Topic:"

Comment: Sorry, I had misunderstood the requirement. Answer amended.

Comment: thanks. The li should only be adjusted next to the image not globally - currently it would affect e.g. the alignment of the bullet point after "Topic:", as well

Comment: Just give it a more specific selector, e.g. a class.